# post story from website under games category

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I want our game to be able to post to the players news feed when they play a game, get a high score or complete a level.
I know Candy Crush shows up under a Game category if I click on my own profile I will see this on the left side. Below it I see Recent Activities. I can get a post to show under Recent Activities but can't figure out how to get it to show under Games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be listed as a game, it must have been categorized as a game.

go to your facebook's developer profile and enter in your app's configuration. You can change the app category on the "App details" section. If you don't find it, just follow this link inserting your App's id: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your_app_id/appdetails

Remember that your app has to be in "live mode" (not sandbox mode) to be listed on public timelines.

Note: Facebook's game histories are not always shown. Most recent and most played games are displayed first, the same happens with actions/achievements. scores are only shown if a friend passes our score, you make a highscore... Read the docs about that, you'll learn almost everything you must know:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements/